# Doctrine 2 ORM - Search in oneToMany relation (QueryBuilder)

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm trying resolve following problem.

I have OrderEntity and in OrderEntity is relation ship to OrderStatusHistory (OneToMany).

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="OrderStatusHistory", mappedBy="order")
 */
protected $statuses;
```

OrderStatusHistory entity:

```
class OrderStatusHistory extends BaseEntity
{

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Order",cascade={"persist"})
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="order_id", referencedColumnName="id")
         **/
        protected $order;

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="OrderStatus",cascade={"persist"})
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="status_id", referencedColumnName="id")
         **/
        protected $status;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
         */
        protected $time;


        public function __construct()
        {
                $this->time = new \DateTime('now');
        }

}
```

And now i need select order where was last *status* with ID 4. I'm tried many variants with QB, but any of them does not work.

Comment: For example joining that table with QB and then search with "IS IN".

Comment: That doesn't make sense, your order only has one status, correct? One to Many as in one status can be associated with many orders, but each order has one status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's several ways, you can join to that table and use WITH, or you can use `WHERE`, or you can just use the ID. Here's some examples:

Using DQL:

```
$dql = "SELECT o
FROM Order o
WHERE o.orderStatus = 4"
```

or

```
$dql = "SELECT o
FROM Order o
INNER JOIN o.orderStatus orderStatus
WITH orderStatus.id = 4"
```

OR:

```
$dql = "SELECT o
FROM Order o
INNER JOIN o.orderStatus orderStatus
WHERE orderStatus.id = 4"
```

Or Query Builder:

```
$queryBuilder->select('o')
             ->from('Order', 'o')
             ->where('o.orderStatus = 4');
```

Comment: I know how to do it with using DQL, but I need do it with QueryBuilder. Your part with Query Builder will not work, because it's oneToMany, I'm tried that.

Comment: That should work fine. You know you can take any DQL and use it to build a query? Why do you HAVE to use QB? If you know how to do it in DQL, what is the DQL for it?

Comment: I know, but then you must associate entities with table names, or am I wrong?

Comment: You never refer to table names in DQL or Query Builder, only in Annotations. Just like you don't refer to column names, but rather properties.